# Apache Commons BeanUtilsBean - exclude attributes from describe()

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I'm using `BeanutilsBean.describe()` method to grab data for an audit trail. It works just fine - that's not the question!

However there are certain attributes which do not need to be audited. These are recorded as strings in a list. So for example if you had an attribute `DomainObject.myValue` the list would contain `"myValue"` so that the result of the call made to `DomainObject.getMyValue()` is not included in the audit trail.

Currently the code gets all the attributes from `BeanutilsBean.describe()` and then iterates through them to discard the unwanted ones.

What I want to be able to do is configure the `BeanUtilsBean` instance with that list of attribute names to exclude so that it doesn't ever call those methods. So in my example,  DomainObject.getMyValue() is never called at all.

I can't work out if that is possible from looking through the API or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, filtering as you're doing is the simplest way.  The source of that method makes no provision for any kind of configurable filtering.  There are really only two options that I can see while using `BeanUtilsBean`:

- Call `describe()` and then filter the results (what you're doing now).  You could wrap this up in a static method with a signature like `public static Map<String, String> describeBean(Object bean, String... excludedProperties)`
- Roll your own utility method (signature like the above) that copies the implementation of `describe()` but does the filtering during the initial iteration.  This would be more performant as it wouldn't require an additional pass through the `Map`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the code I used to solve this.

It's a slightly amended copy of `BeanUtilsBean.describe()` which doesn't call the excluded attribute getters; it's the "Roll your own" option from [ach's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368116/apache-commons-beanutilsbean-exclude-attributes-from-describe#answer-15372131) (the first option has been in use in live code for a couple of years but it's never sat right with me!).

```
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.DynaBean;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.DynaProperty;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils;

public class BeanUtilsBeanExtensions {

    private static final BeanUtilsBean BEAN_UTILS_BEAN = BeanUtilsBean
                    .getInstance();

    public BeanUtilsBeanExtensions() {
    }

    /**
     * Extends BeanUtilsBean.describe() so that it can be given a list of
     * attributes to exclude. This avoids calling methods which might derive
     * data which don't happen to be populated when the describe() call is made
     * (and therefore could throw exceptions) as well as being more efficient
     * than describing everything then discarding attributes which aren't
     * required.
     *
     * @param bean
     *            See BeanUtilsBean.describe()
     * @param excludedAttributeNames
     *            the attribute names which should not be described.
     * @return See BeanUtilsBean.describe()
     */
    public Map<String, String> describe(Object bean,
                    Set<String> excludedAttributeNames)
                    throws IllegalAccessException,
                    InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {

        // This method is mostly just a copy/paste from BeanUtilsBean.describe()
        // The only changes are:
        // - Removal of reference to the (private) logger
        // - Addition of Reference to a BeanUtilsBean instance
        // - Addition of calls to excludedAttributeNames.contains(name)
        // - Use of generics on the Collections
        // - Calling of a copy of PropertyUtilsBean.getReadMethod()

        if (bean == null) {
            return (new java.util.HashMap<String, String>());
        }

        Map<String, String> description = new HashMap<String, String>();
        if (bean instanceof DynaBean) {
            DynaProperty[] descriptors = ((DynaBean) bean).getDynaClass()
                            .getDynaProperties();
            for (int i = 0; i < descriptors.length; i++) {
                String name = descriptors[i].getName();
                if (!excludedAttributeNames.contains(name)) {
                    description.put(name,
                                    BEAN_UTILS_BEAN.getProperty(bean, name));
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors = BEAN_UTILS_BEAN
                            .getPropertyUtils().getPropertyDescriptors(bean);
            Class<? extends Object> clazz = bean.getClass();
            for (int i = 0; i < descriptors.length; i++) {
                String name = descriptors[i].getName();
                if (!excludedAttributeNames.contains(name)
                                && getReadMethod(clazz, descriptors[i]) != null) {
                    description.put(name,
                                    BEAN_UTILS_BEAN.getProperty(bean, name));
                }
            }
        }
        return description;
    }

    /*
     * Copy of PropertyUtilsBean.getReadMethod() since that is package-private.
     */
    private Method getReadMethod(Class<? extends Object> clazz,
                    PropertyDescriptor descriptor) {
        return MethodUtils.getAccessibleMethod(clazz,
                        descriptor.getReadMethod());
    }

}
```